# Executing Shell script from Java code

Tags: java, mount

I have the gui which have the button as "mount to server"....am having the ubuntu client and server system.....When I click the mount button ,it should mount to server folder...
for example, one folder name "OUTPUT" is in the server..in client machine folder is "OUTPUT FILES"...through linux command i can mount the server "OUTPUT" folder from client folder "OUTPUT FILES"....
But , in java when i press the mount button, it should mount the server "OUTPUT" folder..should i need any shellscript code?...how to do?
and how to get the server system ip address?...can u plz anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to do this (mount stuff) daily?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a shell script to mount the server folder onto your client's filesystem.  Once you have that working, you can just execute this shell script from Java code using Runtime class.

```
    String IPAddress = "...";
    String script= "/path/to/your/script.sh";
    String[] cmd = {script, IPAddress};
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec(cmd);
```

Comment: hi thanks.but in tat shell script which should have the ip address...how to specify the client ip address?

Comment: You could have the shell script take IP adrress as commandline parameter. And then pass on the IP from java.  I have modified the code above for this.